# Nexus 7 NFC interfering with Wireless charging

Tags: android, nfc, wireless, battery

From my initial research and experience with wireless chargers for my Nexus 7, it appears that there are issues with wireless chargers interfering and causing issues with NFC functionality. Note, I am not talking about doing both simultaneously. Rather, I am speaking of whether there are detrimental effects on the NFC antenna due to wireless charging over time. I gather that both inductive charging and NFC use the same coil on Nexus 7 (?)

I have personally seen wirelessly charged Nexus 7's NFC scans/tags not registered, but do not know for sure if these two are related for sure. My basic understanding is that the NFC antenna is right near the wireless charging area in the back of the device.

Moreover, wireless charging it's too slow; often times, it seems as though it's slowing down the battery drainage than actively charging it.

Questions to the community are

**1**- what's the best wireless charger out there? Specifically, one that does not interfere with NFC functionality both at a hardware and software level?

**2**- if the NFC functionality is hurt, what's the best way to troubleshoot it? I am experiencing inconsistent scans-- 1 out 5 scans are not registered and the device needs to be powe cycled.

Comment: Is there a reason that this is being asked on StackOverflow rather than the Android Enthusiasts SE?  Seems like you may get more/better answers there.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Is there a way to move it or should I create a new post?

Comment: There ought to be a way to move it, but if there is, I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

We've had some experience with this behavior. Specifically with our [NFC Patch Kit products](http://flomio.com/shop/nfc-readers/nfc-patch-kit/) rather than wireless charging. The issue is with the Automatic Gain Control (AGC) system built into NFC controllers. It's main purpose is to adjust the power output on the antenna coil to optimize the field while minimizing battery drain. Here's a snap shot from the [BCM20793S spec sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7idbhuqn57n70j/BCM20793S-datasheet.pdf?dl=0) (same as BCM20793M in Nexus 7 only without Secure Element):

> A “false alarm rate” can occur when the [low power target detect] can be triggered by
>   metallic objects, but any trigger will be qualified by a full poll
>   event and therefore can be discounted if it is not a real target. The
>   control algorithm includes a background calibration, so it
>   auto-adjusts to a background baseline to account for drift and
>   changing conditions.

So what's happening is that the Nexus 7 antenna is getting desensitized as the wireless charging pad is put in the field. If seems the Nexus 7 firmware stack is not smart enough to  detect the wireless charging presence and deactivate the NFC controller altogether to prevent the problem. Or at least trigger a recalibration of the LPTD mode. We do this with [our FloBLE product](http://flomio.com/shop/nfc-readers/floble-nfc-reader-mpos/).

So to answer your questions explicitly:

1. what's the best wireless charger out there? Specifically, one that does not interfere with NFC functionality both at a hardware and software level?

In order to achieve good coupling between wireless charger and device, they need to have a tuned induction coil. So you can't really swap out the Nexus charger for another and expect to improve anything. The issues above will remain and you'll probably end up with a weakened recharge experience. That said, I've found the [Duracell Powermats](http://www.duracellpowermat.com/duracellpowermat-powermats/) effective in good wireless charging performance.

2. if the NFC functionality is hurt, what's the best way to troubleshoot it? I am experiencing inconsistent scans-- 1 out 5 scans are not registered and the device needs to be power cycled.

This is a SW bug of the Nexus 7 low level NFC management system. You should be able to reset the LPTD calibration by enabling/disabling NFC from the device Settings screen. I've found power cycling is the only way to achieve it though. You could [log a defect](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) against the Nexus 7 2013 board support package (BSP) and reference this post.

Comment: what is the best way for us to connect? I'd love to discuss a few issues.

Comment: I have noticed that the behavior varies with OS and with root access-- is there a reason why?

Also, over time, as we put the device through wireless charging, is there degradation effect on the NFC (asking since you mentioned, wireless charging desensitizes NFC coil)?

Comment: You can always reach out through our website http://flomio.com The management of AGC is a software thing so swapping out OSs will influence behavior for that reason. Also, desensitizing of the NFC coil is a temporary thing given it's controlled by software. Power cycling the device will trigger a recalibration and you'll be back to normal.